# Woocommerce - How to add 5 stars to all products to test design

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I haven't been able to find this on google and I thought this was a common requirement.

Is there a way to add a 5 stars (or whatever rating) to my products with a single plugin or PHP code? I need to show stars in every catalog so I can test my design.

Answer (score 5):

[@Nikola](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/111583/nikola-miljkovi%C4%87)'s [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/277935/43098) gives you what you want to need without saving anything to the database. If **you** need to save the values to the database and directly execute SQL, you can do the following.

Basically WooCommerce stores product reviews data as a postmeta under [meta keys](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/bdba4f76362c3b3646c775c10e87f32dd062a25c/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php#L52-L54)

- _wc_rating_count
- _wc_average_rating
- _wc_review_count

```
UPDATE fs_postmeta SET meta_value = 5
WHERE meta_key = '_wc_average_rating' AND post_id = 564;

UPDATE fs_postmeta SET meta_value = 105 
WHERE meta_key = '_wc_review_count' AND post_id = 564;
```

or

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: BK
Version: 0.0.1
*/

function bk_get_all_products(  ) {

    $ps = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1'
    ) );
    $arr = array();
    while($ps->have_posts()){
      $ps->the_post();
      $arr[] = get_the_ID();
    }
    return $arr;
}

add_action('init','bk');
function bk(){
  $products = bk_get_all_products();
  // $re = array(
  //   "1" => 1,
  //   "2" => 2,
  //   "3" => 3,
  //   "4" => 5,
  //   "5" => 6,
  // );
  foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
    update_post_meta( $value, '_wc_average_rating', 1 );
    update_post_meta( $value, '_wc_review_count', 15 );
    // update_post_meta( $value, '_wc_rating_count', $re );
  }
}
```

Remember with this we are not changing the reviews list that appears under product tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need it just for visual purposes, it's better if you don't save the rating value to the database, but instead to just modify the value during runtime:

```
/**
 * Modifies WooCommerce product rating to force a defined value
 * 
 * @return string Modified rating html
 */
function wpse_get_modified_rating_html(){
    /** @var float Rating being shown */
    $rating = 5;
    /** @var int Total number of ratings */
    $count = 1;

    $html  = '<div class="star-rating">';
    $html .= wc_get_star_rating_html( $rating, $count );
    $html .= '</div>';

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_rating_html', 'wc_get_rating_html' );
```

You can add that code to your theme's `functions.php` or you could create a new plugin for that purpose.

Remember to remove the code on production server, since it will force all ratings to show 5 stars!

Comment: Great solution! gonna try and let you know.